# Overflow hides content (should appear while scroll)

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a website which uses snap.js and chart.js.

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MU9aw/9/)

After adding JavaScript to display the content from chart.js while user scroll, seems like it is in some trouble with the following style:

Line 10 - CSS:   `overflow: auto;`

If I delete this style it works perfectly:

[DEMO2 JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MU9aw/10/) (without overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `window` is no longer scrolling.  Instead your `.snap-content` is.  So you'll need to change the `scroll` handler to that element.  You will then also have to modify your calculation a bit to work with this new setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/MU9aw/27/

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = 0;
    var docViewBottom = $(".snap-content").height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemBottom >= docViewTop));
}

$(".snap-content").scroll(function () {
    /* ... */
```

Note that your calculations will get considerably more complicated if your scrolling box does not fill the entire screen as you will need to determine if the element is visible within its box as well as that portion of the box being visible on the screen.

Comment: So maybe this code will give me problems on long term?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the overflow that makes the issue.. It's the

> .snap-content {
>       position: absolute;  }

makes the issue. When I removed it, it works!

The problem is

> $(window).scroll(function() {});

Doesn't fire when I scrolled maybe because since the element is absolute it keeps the original position in the screen without changing it. Make it to relative, and it will work.

Comment: After you answer I was thinking on adding a new snap-content class, but for the moment seems like it also works with the @James Montagne answer. Thanks for your time anyway, I really appreciate it!